# Reference request: positive first chern class of tangent bundle implies anticanonical line bundle is ample

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes, line-bundles

I am searching for a reference (preferably with a proof) for the following result:

Let $X$ be a smooth projective curve, $T_X$ its tangent bundle, $K_X$ its canonical bundle. If $c_1(T_X) > 0$, then $K_X^{-1}$ is ample.

Comment: Unsure about a reference, but this follows at once from the canonical bundle being the inverse (dual) of the tangent bundle, and any line bundle of positive degree (first chern class) being ample.

Comment: Do you know the relationship between $c_1(E)$ and $c_1(\det E)$? What about $c_1(L)$ and $c_1(L^{-1})$?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese : I know $c_1(L) = -c_1(L^{-1})$, but not the relationship between $c_1(E)$ and $c_1(\det E)$.

Comment: Do you know the splitting principle?

Comment: Yes, but I don't see what that has to do with $c_1(E)$ and $c_1(\det E)$.

Comment: You can use the splitting principle to show that $c_1(E) = c_1(\det E)$.

Comment: Aha, so $c_1(E) = \sum c_1(L_i)$ and $c_1(\det E) = c_1(L_1\otimes \ldots \otimes L_n)$. And the rest follows.

Comment: Exactly. Putting everything together, you find that $c_1(K_X^{-1}) = c_1(\det T_X) = c_1(T_X) > 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, one can prove the identity $c_1(\det E) = c_1(E)$ using the splitting principle. Since $K_X^{-1} = \det T_X$, we see that $$c_1(K_X^{-1}) = c_1(\det T_X) = c_1(T_X) > 0$$ and therefore $K_X^{-1}$ is ample. Here we have used the isomorphism $\det(E^*)^* \cong \det E$ to identify $K_X^{-1}$ with $\det(T_X)$ (since $K_X^{-1} = K_X^*$). Alternatively, we could use the identity $c_1(E^*) = -c_1(E)$ to reach the same conclusion: $$c_1(K_X^{-1}) = c_1(K_X^*) = -c_1(K_X) = -c_1(\det T^*_X) = -c_1(T^*_X) = c_1(T_X) > 0.$$